# how to copy data from one table to another table when column count not same

Tags: mysql

I want to copy data from one table to another. first table have fixed no of columns and another table is dynamic in nature has changing columns.
When I go to copy data from one table to another I got error

> column count does not match.

How to resolve this issue so that

I am expecting column count of two tables get same.

Comment: can your try to copy using any SQL interface like dbeaver or phpMyAdmin

Comment: You need to specify the target and source column names..

Answer (score 1):

try by query :

insert into another_table(id, name, etc) select id, name, etc from one_table